# Error message in R: Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : invalid argument type

Tags: r, text-mining, tidytext

I tried to use tidytext to analyze some text and use the code below; however got an error message:

```
dt %>% unnest_tokens(output, input, token="ngrams", n=3)
```

> ```
> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : invalid argument type
> ```

This is the error message I got on my company's internal R platform, however the code runs on my local R studio. What should I do to correct the error? (both input and output are strings)

Comment: That's the error you get from dplyr when something is wrong with the input, but it's not very helpfully specific. In this case it's impossible to diagnose without [a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610).

Comment: You'll need to look at the object `dt` in detail and see what is going on with it. Is there an `input` column? Is it of type character? The problem is probably something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I had what appeared to be the same issue as the OP described here.  The following code generated the same error, which is straight out of the package documentation.

library(janeaustenr)

austen_bigrams <- austen_books() %>% unnest_tokens(bigram, text, token = "ngrams", n = 2)

Using old.packages() I saw that my dplyr and tidyr were outdated, so I updated them with install.packages() and now the error is gone.  Evidently the package version was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and updated my **dplyr** and **tidytext** packages which caused the error to go away. (I tried to add this as a comment to Jason's answer, but don't yet have enough reputation).

Comment: Add it as a comment to the question.

Comment: It says I must have 50 reputation to comment on either the original question or someone else's answer